# Saving a video from tello Drone

Tags: python

Following up from my previous post which I solved and also by using this to guide me "https://github.com/hanyazou/TelloPy/blob/develop-0.7.0/tellopy/examples/video_effect.py"

I eventually managed to get a live footage from the drone, but I have no idea how to get that video saved onto my PC.